# How do I get the user ID of the user that was updated in WordPress?

Tags: plugins, users, updates

I want to run a custom function in my plugin that notifies me of the user that's email has been updated in wordpress backend. But i am not sure how do I get the user ID of that user, since this action hook `add_action( 'update_user', 'when_update_user' );` requires me to pass an user ID to run `when_update_user()` function when an administrator updates the user data. Does anyone have any idea regarding it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `profile_update` & `user_register`.

[`user_register` is called after a user is created.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register)

```
add_action( 'user_register', 'myplugin_registration_save', 10, 1 );
function myplugin_registration_save( $user_id ) {
    // Do stuff with $user_id
}
```

[`profile_update` is called after a user is updated.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Action_Reference/profile_update)

```
add_action( 'profile_update', 'my_profile_update', 10, 2 );
function my_profile_update( $user_id, $old_user_data ) {
    // Do stuff with $user_id
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was using the wrong hook, this one helped.